# chkdsk on mounted NTFS partition

Tags: windows, ntfs

I have mounted NTFS partition as Folder on c:\windows\NTFS folder.

How do I perform a chkdsk on the mounted NTFS partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `chkdsk X:\folder` from the Command Prompt (CMD).

If this doesn't work, you will need to mount the partition as a disk.
Note that you can mount this in multiple locations, so you don't need to
undo the existing mount.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can't.

You can run `chkdsk /offlinescanandfix` which will attempt the chkdsk on the partition when it is next booted (usually for OS partition since you cannot unmount it while the OS is loaded).

If it is not the OS partition - you can unmount the drive, and then run the chkdsk, and then mount it again (using Disk Management).